# How to move an Azure application created under a personal account to a directory?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have an application in Azure that's listed under 'App registrations' -> 'Applications from personal account' that I would like to move to a directory so other users in the company can manage it.

There's an info message that has this to say about personal account applications:

> These applications are associated with the account xxxxxxxxxxxxx but
>   are not contained within any directory.  They are shown here so you
>   can manage them, but will not be available to other users or admins in
>   this directory.

Is there any way to move it? I haven't been able to find any info on this, and seeing as it's in use in the wild by thousands of users I would prefer not to create a new one and have them re-authorize.

Comment: I think no. But I could be wrong also :|

Comment: Even I think the same.. you may want to check with Azure Support. At least I'm not aware of explicit documentation for this scenario.

Comment: Without a paid support subscription it's not possible to get direct support as far as I've been able to make out, but I might post on the MS forums if no-one from MS sees this :)

Comment: @TonyJu it is, thanks Tony.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have confirmed this with Azure support engineer. The answer is no. Here is the reply. Hope it helps.

> Your applications were created in converged app portal by your
>   Microsoft account. After lab tested, the Apps owner cannot be changed
>   to a work account because the MSA account is not contained within any
>   AAD.  The workaround would be re-create it in the new tenant for your
>   application.

Comment: Wow, this is so annoying...  Thanks Microsoft.